# While loop with A+ promises in JavaScript / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I need to keep calling remote API until I get the response I need, and I would like to use the Official A+ promises in node.js.  Sync psudo code:

```
params = { remote api call params }
while (true) {
    result = callRemoteApi(params)
    if isGood(result) {
        onSuccess(result)
        break
    }
    params = modify(params)
}
```

I am using the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) lib for requests, so the result might be something like this:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var task = request({params})
        .then(function (result) {
            if (isGood(result)) {
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                task = request({new params}).then(this_function);
            }
        });
```

P.S. This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238793/177275, but I would like a non-q-based implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work well:

```
var remoteApiCall = function(num){
    // fake function to resolve promise if random number in range
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        return ((Math.random()*10) < num)
            ? resolve(true)
            : reject(false);
    })
}

function getUntil(num){
    return remoteApiCall(num).then(function(result){
        if (result) {
            return result  
        } else {
            // call again until you get valid response
            return getUntil(num)
        }
    })
}

getUntil(num).then(...)
```

Comment: Nice solution and more generally - thanks for helping with the promise tag. Note that the nice thing about this solution is that it's platform agnostic.

Comment: You are rejecing with undefined while the calling code simply expects a resolution with falsy value

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks and my pleasure... just trying pay it forward the help I have received from all of you

Comment: @Esailija THANKS.. I have cleaned up :)

Answer (score 2):

The following solution addresses a few specific problems:

- how to break the (otherwise endless) loop
- how to access the result of a previously failed attempt
- how to incorporate your `params = modify(params)`

The problem can be broken down into two sections:

- a repeater/promise runner (that itself returns a promise so we can hook `onSuccess` to it)
- a promise provider - a function that creates promises for the repeater

The repeater would look like this:

```
function repeatUntilSuccess(promiseProvider) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var counter = 0;
        function run(failedResult) {
            var p = promiseProvider(failedResult, counter++);
            if (p instanceof Promise) {
                p.then(resolve).catch(run);
            } else {
                reject(p);
            }
        }
        run();
    });
}
```

The "loop" happens in this line: `p.then(resolve).catch(run);`. The repeater keeps calling the promise provider until the promise it returns resolves (in which case the repeater resolves) *or* until it no longer provides a promise (in which case the repeater rejects).

A promise provider can be any `function(previousResult, counter)` that returns a promise (or not, if you wish to stop the loop).

```
var params = {/* ... */};
function nextRequest(previousResult, counter) {
    if (counter >= 10) return "too many attempts";
    if (previousResult) params = modify(params);
    return apiRequest(params);
}
```

*(This setup assumes that `apiRequest()` returns a promise)*

Now you can do this:

```
repeatUntilSuccess(nextRequest).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
```

---

Since your question includes the side-task of wrapping an HTTP request in a promise:

```
function apiRequest(params) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return request(params).then(function (result) {
            if (isGood(result)) {
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                reject(result);
            }
       });
    });
}
```

---

Open the browser console and run the following snippet to see it in action.

```js
function repeatUntilSuccess(promiseProvider) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var counter = 0;
        function run(failedResult) {
            var p = promiseProvider(failedResult, counter++);
            if (p instanceof Promise) {
                p.then(resolve).catch(run);
            } else {
                reject(p);
            }
        }
        run();
    });
}

// mockup promise that resoves or rejects randomly after a timeout
function randomPromise(num){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function () {
            var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * num * 10);
            if (randomNum < num) {
                resolve(randomNum);
            } else {
                reject(randomNum);
            }
        }, 300);
    });
}

// promise provider
function nextPromise(prev, i) {
    if (prev) console.info("failed attempt #" + i + ": " + prev);
    if (i >= 5) return "too many attempts:" + i;
    return randomPromise(100);
}

// run it!
repeatUntilSuccess(nextPromise).then(function (result) {
    console.log("success", result);
}).catch(function (result) {
    console.log("failed", result);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I disagree. My code *looks like* that, it isn't that. (Okay, `apiReques()` could be made [marginally simpler](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28592714/revisions#rev24bb3ea8-9d60-47f9-ae34-32fa5375fb65), but the rest?)

Comment: **1)** Unfortunately your last version in that Gist isn't equivalent anymore to my original idea. **2)** I don't understand how `Promise.resolve()`  as a way to create a new promise is better than `new Promise()`. It's fewer lines, but is it better? (I do understand that `Promise.resolve(p)` is nicer, though.) **3)** I don't subscribe to the idea that rejected promises are like exceptions. If a promise encapsulates a process that can fail naturally (like setting a value and getting back a "not allowed") then I would expect that promise to *reject*, not resolve with a falsey value.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong with my last point. Assuming I talk to an HTTP API in order to set the value `foo` to 5. That request can fail on multiple levels. It can fail physically (timeout), it can fail on server (404 or 500), it can fail in the application (access denied). I would expect a rejected promise in every one of these cases, because the promise was to set the value `foo` to five, and it didn't work. Resolving the promise with "false" for the "access denied" case does not feel right.

Comment: The last version is not equivalent but the one just before is. `Promise.resolve()` just gives you an empty promise - you don't have to create your own completion source and your code is not concerned with all the wiring of rejections and errors so it's a lot easier to not get wrong - your `apiRequest` function can just be `function apiRequest(){ request(params).then(function(res){ if(!isGood(res)) throw res; return res; });}`. In HTTP APIs I believe that a rejection is for a timeout or an application fail is good but I would not reject on a 404 error myself at the HTTP request layer.

Comment: Well, when properly abstracted, `setFoo(5).then(joy).catch(noJoy)` wouldn't even expose the fact that HTTP is involved. When the server replies "no" that's not an HTTP error, but but it *still* means `noJoy` for me. Right?

Comment: Are you talking about an RPC failure here or a protocol failure? When you make an HTTP request the promise wrapper for that should reject if the request itself failed - not if the request was successful and the server returned a response we didn't expect. When wrapping that API in an RPC API you can check if the server did not do what we expected it to and `throw` which would give you that behavior. Anyway - if you want to talk more about this I'm often in the JS room in chat. It kind of got offtopic here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71265/discussion-between-tomalak-and-benjamin-gruenbaum).