# Using Promise, getting error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using promise and was following [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217736/while-loop-with-promises), but when I run the script I am getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. My code appears as the following:

```
var completedLinks = ["http://www.example.com/1","http://www.example.com/2","http://www.example.com/3"]
function fetchSiteDetails(arr){
  arr.reduce(function(promise, email) {
    console.log(email)
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

fetchSiteDetails(completedLinks).then(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

I guess that `fetchSiteDetails` isn't valid to use `then` on, but I'm not sure why?

Comment: fetchSiteDetails doesn't return a promise? :)

Comment: what are you doing besides logging to console in the reduce? You need multiple promises if each loop is async

Comment: Where is the asynchronous task that necessitates the usage of promises in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning a promise from `fetchSiteDetails`, nor are you producing a value with `arr.reduce`. Try something like this:

```js
function log(message) {
  document.body.innerHTML += message + '<br />';
}

function fetchSiteDetails(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(promise, email) {
    log(email);
    return promise;
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

fetchSiteDetails([1, 2, 3]).then(function() {
  log('Done');
});
```

Comment: @charlietfl The then will work as the initial value is a promise and it is not changed in any way through the reduce, which WILL return a promise, but the function still does nothing useful.

Comment: If I add something inside, such as a request to cheerio, will it wait to complete that job before starting on the next link?

Comment: @maudulus No because you're using `.reduce` which runs synchronously. Instead, you'd likely have to setup a series of promises which only resolve the one you're returning after all of the other ones have completed.

Answer (score 1):

It's like you want the same behavior that `Promise.all()` already provides.
Try something like this:

```
var completedLinks = ["http://www.example.com/1","http://www.example.com/2","http://www.example.com/3"]
function fetchSiteDetails(arr){
  return Promise.all(arr.map(function(email) {
    return Promise.resolve(); // do whatever here, but return a promise !
  }));
}

fetchSiteDetails(completedLinks).then(function() {
  console.log('all done');
});
```