# Promise in loop

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
function reduce(functn, intialPromise) {
    var proceed = true;
    var promise = intialPromise;
    do {
        functn(promise).then(next => {
            proceed = next.proceed;
            promise = next.promise;
        });
    } while(proceed);
    return promise;
}
```

Worker function

```
let promiseFunction = (promise) => {
    let proceed = true;
    return promise.then(() => {

        // some processing in which proceed can become false

        let nextPromise = {};
        if(proceed){
            nextPromise.proceed = true;
            nextPromise.promise = next promise task;
        }
        else {
            nextPromise.proceed = false;
            nextPromise.promise = Promise.resolve(true);
        }
        return Promise.resolve(nextPromise);
    });
};
```

Execution

```
reduce(promiseFunction, initialPromise).then(() => {
    return success;
});
```

This code is looping continuously.

The idea was to have chained promise. The data on which promise acts is big say 1 GB. but the allocated memory for promise processing is low - 100 MB. So the promise has to run in chain - taking small batches which fit into memory.

Also currently tied to ES6 code, and polyfills/transpiling is not added yet. Hence expecting result in ES6 code.

PS: Not a javascript expert, kindly  apologise for blunders

Comment: what are you providing in place of `initialPromise` ?

Comment: Its a valid promise - assume its `Promise.resolve(true)`

Comment: `then` returns a promise without executing the handlers supplied in call. These are executed asynchronously, some time later, if and when the promise `then` was called on is settled. The code that changes `proceed` is asynchronous, executed later, and does not change the loop variable while the loop is executing - so it loops forever. Try searching for "recursive promise function" (543 results on SO)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217736/while-loop-with-promises, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24660096/1048572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `do-while` is synchronous (if I'm right).
Have a look at [JavaScript ES6 promise for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328932/javascript-es6-promise-for-loop)

With `async/await` it should work

```
async function reduce(functn, intialPromise) {
    var proceed = true;
    var promise = intialPromise;
    do {
        const result = await functn(promise);
        proceed = result.proceed;
        promise = result.promise;
    } while(proceed);
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tobias-timm   answer in the above link solves the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329190/7348879

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick look at this:

At no point do you set "proceed" to "false", so it will continue to loop your do-while.

Comment: proceed = next.proceed; can set it

Comment: It can. But it might not - and it wasn't specified (or considered relevant to be placed in code).

Comment: its mentioned in comment body `// some processing in which  proceed can become false`